# function template argument deduction in a class

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have always thought that function template argument deduction can work only for pure function like below and not for classes.

```
template <class T1,class T2, class T3>
T foo(T2 a, T3 b)
{
   T o;
   //..do something
   return o;
}
```

Today Just by chance I put such function within a class and it did work like below.

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
   template <class T1,class T2, class T3>
   T foo(T2 a, T3 b)
   {
     T o;
     //..do something
     return o;
   }
}
```

I am using g++ 4.4 in Linux.
Should this have failed or I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template deduction works for **function** and for **method**.

If you have template class, something like:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass 
{
public:
   MyClass(T1 a, T2 b)
};
```

You can't deduce type with something like

```
MyClass m(42, 53);           // Illegal
auto m = MyClass(42, 53);    // Illegal
```

You have to explicitly give type:

```
MyClass<int, int> m(42, 53); // Legal
```

Comment: what about operator overloading for a class? Can I create a template version for those?

Comment: Yes you can, there are function or method. So type deduction works.

Answer (score 4):

> I have always thought that function template argument deduction can
>   work only for pure function like below and not for classes.

It's wrong. There is no difference in deduction in free-functions and in member-functions.